# Why do I get "Can't locate Sub/Identify.pm in @INC" when I use the DateTime module even though I installed the perl-DateTime RPM?

Tags: linux, perl

I am trying to use the module `DateTime` in CentOS so I installed it like this:

```
yum install perl-DateTime
```

and then added `use DateTime` to my script, but I get this error:

```
Can't locate Sub/Identify.pm in @INC (@INC contains:
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3/x86_64-linux-thread-multi
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/5.16.3
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/x86_64-linux-thread-multi /root/perl5/lib/perl5
/usr/local/lib64/perl5 /usr/local/share/perl5
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
/usr/lib64/perl5 /usr/share/perl5 .) at
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/namespace/autoclean.pm line 200. Compilation
failed in require at /root/perl5/lib/perl5/DateTime/Locale.pm line 11.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/DateTime/Locale.pm line 11. Compilation failed
in require at /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DateTime.pm line 45. BEGIN
failed--compilation aborted at
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DateTime.pm line 45. Compilation failed
in require at myscript.pl line 8. BEGIN failed--compilation aborted
at myscript.pl line 8.
```

I have no idea what's going on. I already installed several packages through the CPAN. This is the first time I've tried with `yum install` and it doesn't work. Any ideas?

Comment: Package might not be installed in desired location. Check where the package is installed. Then Check `@INC` variable in perl script. Check the path available in that.

Comment: Try run `sudo cpan Sub::Identify`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### TL;DR

This is why it's a bad idea to mix modules installed via a package manager and via CPAN.

---

It looks like you installed DateTime with yum, but DateTime::Locale with CPAN. You can see this by following the dependency chain in your error message:

```
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/namespace/autoclean.pm --> CPAN
/root/perl5/lib/perl5/DateTime/Locale.pm     --> CPAN
/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl/DateTime.pm     --> yum
```

The newest version of namespace::autoclean depends on Sub::Identify, which seems to be missing from `@INC`.

So did yum install a package with missing dependencies? Nope, it installed an older version of DateTime::Locale, when namespace::autoclean wasn't a dependency:

```
$ cpan -D DateTime::Locale | grep -oP '[\d.]+(?=\s+up)'     # newest version
1.14
$ yum info perl-DateTime-Locale | grep -oP 'Version\D+\K.+' # yum version
0.45
$ rpm -q --requires perl-DateTime-Locale | grep autoclean
$
```

But since you put `/root/perl5/lib/perl5` before the system perl directories in `@INC`, you're loading the version installed by CPAN, which does need namespace::autoclean and Sub::Identify. Of course, yum has no way to know that.

I'm not sure why Sub::Identify is missing...you may have deleted it, or it may simply be installed outside of `@INC`. You *could* try to re-install it with CPAN, but it would be better to:

- remove `/root/perl5/*` from `@INC` and only install modules in the system perl with yum
- use [perlbrew](https://perlbrew.pl/) or [plenv](https://github.com/tokuhirom/plenv) to create your own local installation of perl and install modules with cpan